# How can you see the actual runtype of a type parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Say I have code like this

```
       public bool ProcessChangeRequest(ChangeRequest cr, ChangeCommitted cc)
        {
        DbObject.AssertDirectAccessToDatabase();
        SeqlDatabase<ContextT>.CheckObjectType(cr, typeof(ConfigT));
        return SeqlDatabase<ContextT>.Instance.TryUpdate(delegate()
           {
               SeqlDatabase<ContextT>.UpdateModification(cr);
                  .....
```

When I am debugging, how can I see what the actual type of ContextT is?

Comment: Have you tried using `typeof(ContextT)` in the watch window? I don't know whether that would work...

Comment: Thanks! So simple, but if you don't know. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming ContextT is in scope when you're on your breakpoint.

There are several methods to do this, one is to hover your mouse over an reference of ContextT the code and examine the variable - personally I find that dialog a little convoluted.

Personally I open my immediate window and type:

```
? ContextT.GetType().FullName
```

Note that GetType() will get you far more information but the FullName property ensures you only get one line instead of dozens of irrelevant properties!

typeof(ContextT) has much the same effect as .GetType() (at least in this case it does).

Comment: If you get a null on ContextT in debug while you are 100% sure that you are still in scope (VS2010 has such issues in debugging for example) then uses GC.KeepAlive(ContextT) before the end of your method.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Immediate Window` (Ctrl + D + I) and enter `typeof(ConfigT)`.

`QuickWatch` (Ctrl + D + Q) also works.